# Mongodb: select the last event from a time series

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to build a time series in a Mongo database, and based on advice from several SO posts, am going with one document for each event, such as:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("51a67033868eda7666b0a49c"),
  station_id: 12,
  timestamp: ISODate("2013-05-29T21:16:35.929Z"),
  value: 50
}
```

Getting the history for a particular station is easy enough(`db.mydata.find({station_id: 12}, {timestamp: 1})`).

The bigger challenge is getting the latest value across all of my stations. (Note that the latest timestamp is going to be different for each station, so I can't do a naive query.) In SQL, I would do:

```
SELECT station_id, timestamp, value
FROM mydata
WHERE (station_id, timestamp) IN (
  SELECT station_id, MAX(timestamp)
  FROM mydata
  GROUP BY station_id
)
```

How would you do something similar in Mongodb? The aggregation framework is pretty powerful, but I can't figure out a way to do this type of analysis using it.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework but it's a little bit tricky.  Here is how:

```
db.mydata.aggregate( [
      { $sort : {timestamp:-1}},
      { $group : { _id : "$station_id",
                 timestamp : {$first:"$timestamp"},
                 value : {$first:"$value"}
      }  }
] )
```

Basically you are sorting your input by timestamp descending - and then you aggregate and for each unique station_id you keep the first timestamp and value you encounter (in sorted order!)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT station_id, timestamp, value
FROM mydata
WHERE (station_id, timestamp) IN (
  SELECT station_id, MAX(timestamp)
  FROM mydata
  GROUP BY station_id
)
```

I think would be something similar to

```
db.aggregate( 
    { $group : { _id : "$station_id", max_timestamp : { $max : timestamp } } },
    { $project : {station_id : 1, max_timestamp : 1, value : 1 } }
)
```

Comment: that won't work - you only have station_id and timestamp coming out of the $group phase.  You can't project value since you didn't preserve it.

Comment: You're right. I thought I may lose something because of being in a different aggregation level, but I didn't think about your solution. I think it is the only way, +1 for it.